filter_input or FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS causing troubles with non-english language in PHPMailer
I am having problems with PHPMailer and no similar answer is helping me.
The problem seems to be in filter_input or FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS but I really don't know how to fix it.
Here is the way I get the POST values for the subject and message
$subject=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'subject',FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$message=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'message',FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);

and here is how I send the values with PHPMailer
$mail=new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SetLanguage( "fr", "phpmailer/language" );
$mail->Encoding = "base64"; 

...
$mail->ContentType='text/plain'; 
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->Subject=($subject);
$mail->Subject=($message);

The goal is simple, to store the message in MySQL in a safe way to prevent getting injections and to send the same message by email.
**The problem: **
My users are based in Sweden and here we use non English vocals like : ö ä å Ö Ä Å
the message arrives to the email with symbols like: &auml &aring
If I change the POST vars to:
$message = $_POST['message'];

Then it works perfect but with no security filtering etc...
How to achieve this?

"The goal is simple, to store the message in MySQL in a safe way to prevent getting injections" - the way to do that is with prepared statements when inserting your data, and escaping when rendering, not destroying the data as you currently are. As to email, just send UTF-8. Not sure what you are sending through this, however. Generally one side of the email form is trusted, either the senders or the recipients. Senders can be guarded as trusted employees with credentials. Recipients can be guarded with "This is an automated email from an untrusted source, please be careful with the contents"

There is no such thing as "safe text".
It's really tempting to think of "sanitisation" as some kind of exorcism: purging the text of "evil" characters, so that it can be trusted everywhere forever. But that's not how it works at all.
Instead, how injection vulnerabilities happen is when text is included which has some special meaning in the context where it's being used. The characters which have special meaning in HTML are different from the ones which have special meaning in SQL, and so on.
There are really only two ways to avoid this safely:

Best of all, completely separate data from instructions, so that the characters in the data are always treated literally, not with special meaning. This is how "parameterized queries" work in databases, and there are very few situations where you should escape for SQL rather than correctly preparing and parameterising your SQL queries.
If that's not possible, carefully escaping special characters for a particular context. Escape text only when you know the exact context, not "in advance, just in case".

Back to your specific question:

FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS is a filter for escaping text for use in an HTML context
But when you send the email, you set $mail->IsHTML(false);

So you're escaping the text for the wrong context. For the context you're using, the only characters with special meaning are probably newlines embedded into the subject, or non-printable characters which might confuse software processing the mail. You may find the PHPMailer library is already checking for these; or you might want to just reject input containing them.
